# Does it make sense to use along with towards?

Tags: grammar

Recently I came across a statements which was hard to understand. It included the use of *along* with *towards*. The statement is like this

> The fact that democracy is the only viable system that can preserve the Indian entity, constitute its whole beyond the sum of the various fragments that go into its making and promote its invaluable genius of stumbling along towards a humane order.

Comment: Read “stumbling along” as a phrasal verb.

Comment: The sentence is malformed. “The fact that X, Y and Z” should be followed by a conclusion. Or it might be missing an “is”.

Comment: Yes. Should start off _The fact **is**_. Then everything's fine.